# Exploding youtube code form string

Tags: php, youtube

Hello everyone i am facing a problem to explode a **MwLAI_TXowc** a from a specific string,
I want to explode **MwLAI_TXowc** from  following youtube code.

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MwLAI_TXowc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Please help me how to explode **MwLAI_TXowc** from youtube embed code in php.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to use PHP function `explode` for this PHP function `pathinfo` is much easier.

```
<?php

$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/MwLAI_TXowc';
$basename = pathinfo($url)['basename'];

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($basename);
echo '<pre>';

?>
```

Output

```
string(11) "MwLAI_TXowc"
```

Or if your PHP doesnt support direct array access with functions

```
<?php 

$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/MwLAI_TXowc';
$pathinfo = pathinfo($url);
$basename = $pathinfo['basename'];

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($basename);
echo '<pre>';

?>
```

Output

```
string(11) "MwLAI_TXowc"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use preg_match for your string

```
$s = '<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MwLAI_TXowc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>';
preg_match('/.*"http.*\/embed\/(.*?)".*/', $s, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```